# Order comments by thread path and by number of total votes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having some trouble ordering comments by their thread path and by number of upvotes of each comment.

Now they are only ordering by thread path. I've tried and searched a lot of things but nothings results.

**This is my query**

```
WITH RECURSIVE first_comments AS (
(
 (
   SELECT id, text, level, parent_id, array[id] AS thread_path, total_votes FROM comments
   WHERE comments."postId" = 1 AND comments."level" = 0 
 )
)
UNION
 (
  SELECT e.id, e.text, e.level, e.parent_id, (fle.thread_path || e.id), e.total_votes
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, text, level, parent_id, total_votes FROM comments
    WHERE comments."postId" = 1
  ) e, first_comments fle
  WHERE e.parent_id = fle.id
 )
)
SELECT id, text, level, total_votes, thread_path from first_comments ORDER BY 5 ASC
```

**This query results in:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id  | level  | total_votes |    thread_path    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   0    |      5      |  {1}              |
| 3   |   1    |      9      |  {1,3}            |
| 7   |   2    |      5      |  {1,3,7}          |
| 9   |   2    |      7      |  {1,3,9}          |
| 11  |   3    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11}       |
| 12  |   4    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11,12}    |
| 13  |   5    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11,12,13} |
| 10  |   1    |     20      |  {1,10}           |
| 2   |   0    |     10      |  {2}              |
| 6   |   1    |      1      |  {2,6}            |
| 4   |   0    |      8      |  {4}              |
| 8   |   1    |      6      |  {4,8}            |
| 5   |   0    |      3      |  {5}              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**And the result should be**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id  | level  | total_votes |    thread_path    |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2   |   0    |     10      |  {2}              |
| 6   |   1    |      1      |  {2,6}            |
| 4   |   0    |      8      |  {4}              |
| 8   |   1    |      6      |  {4,8}            |
| 1   |   0    |      5      |  {1}              |
| 10  |   1    |     20      |  {1,10}           |              
| 3   |   1    |      9      |  {1,3}            |
| 9   |   2    |      7      |  {1,3,9}          |
| 11  |   3    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11}       |
| 12  |   4    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11,12}    |
| 13  |   5    |      0      |  {1,3,9,11,12,13} |
| 7   |   2    |      5      |  {1,3,7}          |
| 5   |   0    |      3      |  {5}              |
--------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm missing here...?

Thank for the help

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because MySQL does not support recursive CTEs.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do a `ORDER BY 4,5` or `ORDER BY 5,4` ?

Comment: I must admit I don't see the progression in the sought result set though.

Comment: I think I understand: ordering by path results the replies come after the comments, which was "replied to". But you want to sort the comments on the same level (top level or the comments, which is replied to the same comment) by `total_votes`?

Comment: @Gordon, thank you but **pozs** really nailed it. Just one more question do you think the title it's appropriate? I found really hard searching this terms

Comment: Right, I was staring at the last columns, without thinking about the meanings of paths (you should call them `thread_path` perhaps?). Now I understand.

Comment: @didierc you're right. Already changed it! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just accumulate another array next to path, witch will contain not just the `id` of each comment in its path, but the `total_votes` (as a negative number) before each id. After that, you can order by that column.

```
WITH RECURSIVE first_comments AS (
(
 (
   SELECT id, text, level, parent_id, array[id] AS path, total_votes,
          array[-total_votes, id] AS path_and_votes
   FROM comments
   WHERE comments."postId" = 1 AND comments."level" = 0 
 )
)
UNION
 (
  SELECT e.id, e.text, e.level, e.parent_id, (fle.path || e.id), e.total_votes,
         (fle.path_and_votes || -e.total_votes || e.id)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id, text, level, parent_id, total_votes FROM comments
    WHERE comments."postId" = 1
  ) e, first_comments fle
  WHERE e.parent_id = fle.id
 )
)
SELECT id, text, level, total_votes, path from first_comments ORDER BY path_and_votes ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07976/2) (only data -- without the recursive CTE)

Answer (score 0):

You want to order by the total votes at the top level.  I think I'll approach this by by using a window function.

Instead of:

```
SELECT id, text, level, total_votes, path
from first_comments
ORDER BY 5 ASC;
```

which explicitly orders by the path.  Try this:

```
select id, text, level, total_votes,
       max(total_votes) over (partition by path[1]) as toplevel_votes
from first_comments
order by 6 desc;
```

This calculates the total votes at the top most level and uses that for ordering.